# FreeBSD package repo - how to do manual signature verification?

Tags: security, package-management, freebsd, openssl, checksum

I'm trying to verify a signature of a package on the [FreeBSD package website](http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:11:amd64/latest/)

```
wget http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:11:amd64/latest/digests.txz
tar xf digests.txz
```

This gives three files: `digests`, `digests.pub` `digests.sig`
I take it that `digests.sig` is a signature for the file `digests` with `digests.pub` as the public key.
But I tried to confirm that:

`openssl dgst -verify digests.pub -signature digests.sig digests`

and got the message

`Verification Failure`

I assume I've got something wrong - can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

EDIT: Based on a hunt through the source code, I *think* the important function is to be found [here](https://github.com/freebsd/pkg/blob/master/libpkg/rsa.c) , called `rsa_verify_cert_cb` which calls `RSA_verify` from the openssl library. But I haven't figured out what is being fed in to it, or whether it's possible to call that function using the `openssl` command line tools.

Comment: This looks relevant https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-ports/2014-February/089751.html However, the command analogous to the one mentioned there   `openssl rsautl -pubin -inkey digests.pub -verify -in digests.sig -asn1parse`   doesn't seem to match either.

Comment: ... that is, doesn't seem to match with `sha256sum digests`

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no "How To" on the Internet for manual FreeBSD package verification, here's what I have figured out.

Trick is that octet string in `openssl rsautl` output is in fact **hash of the string that is SHA256 hash** of a file.

For example, download current `http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:12:amd64/latest/digests.txz`, extract it and do following:

### Method 1 (one-liner using `openssl dgst`)

It is important here to do `tr -d '\n'` to drop new line from standard input, so it is not included in string input for `openssl dgst`.

```
sha256 -q digests | tr -d '\n' | openssl dgst -verify digests.pub -signature digests.sig
```

This command should output `Verified OK`.

### Method 2 (visual comparison of octet string from .sig file with manualy generated hash)

1. Use OpenSSL utility to dump contents from digests.sig

   ```
   openssl rsautl -pubin -inkey digests.pub -verify -in digests.sig -asn1parse
   0:d=0  hl=2 l=  49 cons: SEQUENCE          
   2:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons:  SEQUENCE          
   4:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :sha256
   15:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim:   NULL              
   17:d=1  hl=2 l=  32 prim:  OCTET STRING      
     0000 - ac c6 ac be cd 5e 61 63-62 82 62 4b ba 77 37 6e   .....^acb.bK.w7n
     0010 - 0b fa ea ef 6e 10 21 01-62 64 06 2f d0 f1 60 22   ....n.!.bd./..`"
   ```

   Here you can see that embedded object is a SHA256 hash and its value is `acc6acbecd5e61636282624bba77376e0bfaeaef6e1021016264062fd0f16022`.
2. Now calculate SHA256 of file `digests`:

   ```
   sha256 -q digests
   8db18c93bea414fd8a281f5f3795b2ca4be51479c18b225ff87b8aa957ec2c5d
   ```
3. And finally calculate SHA256 of this string using `echo` command and compare with value returned by `openssl rsautl`:

   ```
   echo -n 8db18c93bea414fd8a281f5f3795b2ca4be51479c18b225ff87b8aa957ec2c5d | sha256
   acc6acbecd5e61636282624bba77376e0bfaeaef6e1021016264062fd0f16022
   ```

Notice how value from step 3. matches value from step 1., so file `digests` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

That message is saying that the public key does not match the file you downloaded. According to the manpage for dgst *-verify filename verify the signature using the the public key in "filename".*  ***The output is either "Verification OK" or "Verification Failure"*** The most likely cause is that the file got corrupted during the download. I would try to download it again and if it continues to fail the check then that's a sign of a compromised download link (but since it's from the freebsd website I'd suspect it's simply a download error. Even then I'd verify the new download just to be on the safe side). If you have a slow/unreliable internet connection it may take a few tries to get it to download right. If you ever need to check for info on commands it's always a good idea to check the manpage (man )

Comment: This was a while ago, but I'm pretty confident that it wasn't a download error (or a compromised download) since I tried it several times.